# Sharepoint list using a column (tags) for searching

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a Sharepoint list with 2 columns. The first column is called "Description" and is a multiple lines column. In the second column called "Keywords" i want to use it to specify keywords that the first column contains.

I could use the column Title to specify the keywords but the column Title is limited to 255 characters. So i have used the Metadata column where i can store multiple keywords. But how
can I use the metadata column for searching?

Gr.P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed metadata column could be searched in the whole site by default. Normally you could use Managed Metadata when dealing with cross site publishing or global search-related metadata.

For searching, if you create a managed metadata column, just wait for a while, then the result will appear in the search box after you type in the kerwords:

[image]

[image]

---

If the answer is helpful, please click "√" on the left panel of the answer and kindly upvote it.

Comment: Hi, I am checking to see if the problem has been resolved. If you have any questions or progress, you can contact me in time.